# Unity 2019 - linebreak \n not working for UI text elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am having some difficulty getting linebreaks to work for my Unity UI elements. (Unity 2019.2.17f1 Personal)

What I'm doing is:

```
string twoLinesOfText = LanguagePack.getTextByID(ID);
```

result:

```
twoLinesOfText = "Text line 1\nText line 2"
```

Expected output:

```
Text line 1
Text line 2
```

Reality:

```
Text line 1\nText line 2
```

I have tried using "\n", "\\n" and "\r\n". None of these give the intended result.

I assign the text to the component using

```
UITextComponent.GetComponent<Text>().text = twoLinesOfText;
```

Can this direct assignment be a problem? Do i need to push my string through a toString() or parse it somehow for the \n to be recognised?

Workaround:
I have a workaround. By using an XML file for my LanguagePack, and inserting (enter) linebreaks in the base file, I feed the linebreaks into my Unity UI elements. Obviously this is not ideal.
Reading back the strings in Debug.Log does not show which linebreak code was ultimately used: it just breaks the string according to the (enter) linebreaks in the XML file.

Comment: have you tried <\br>

Answer (score 3):

You can't import it trought Language Package. What you should do is :

```
string line1 = LanguagePackage.getTextByID(ID1);
string line2 = LanguagePackage.getTextByID(ID2);
string twoLinesOfText  = line1 + "\n" + line2;
UITextComponent.GetComponent<Text>().text = twoLinesOfText;
```

Comment: Yes this works, thank you.


It means many extra I/O runs, though. I think it might be cheaper to collect the whole text in one go ->  split on "\n" and foreach the results.

Answer (score 0):

Run into this problem myself, a little investigation showed that what I thought was \n in the string had been converted to \\n so it showed in the text box as \n.
Converting it during debugging to just \n got me the multiline text I wanted.
Now to investigate where in my data chain it got converted :-)

Ok, investigation complete. A file was saved, on my PC from a program in Visual Basic using the File.WriteAllLines function, one of those lines had a couple of instances of \n. A look at that file in notepad shows it had correctly written that line. The problem came when I used File.ReadAllLines in my unity program as it converted those \n instances to \\n. As far as I can tell this is not a documented action, in fact it's possible, on reading the MS docs, to think that it would have split that line into multiple lines, which it doesn't do.
I checked in my VB program and File.ReadAllLines does not behave in this way there. It's probably something to do with the environment, VB does not use \n, C# does. I fixed the problem by tagging a replace onto the string e.g. string.Replace("\\n", "\n"). It's entirely possible that attempting to write a string from C# with File.WriteAllLines could also mess with \n.

Geez, this was hard to write as the Editor here messes with \\n and convert it to \n and I end up having to use \\\n

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For people who encounter this issue. You Could try to use some HTML similar syntax and see whether it works or not.

Eg:
Using 
 for newline instead of \n

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. TextMeshPro now uses HTML break code to do a line break.
For some reason, it won't show here, but it is:
Less-Than BR Greater-Than

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).